# Difficulty in identifying outliers beyond limits

Tags: mean, outliers

I have a various files, all containing data at 1-minute interval. File structure is as follows where D/T represents Date-Time, C1 and C2 are like constants in this task.

```
D/T  AB  EF  C1  C2
20100101W00:01:00  112  25  1100  1910
20100101W00:02:00  121  37  1100  1911
20100101W00:03:00  119  36  1101  1912
20100101W00:04:00  115  43  1102  1901
..
..
```

I have lower and upper limits for columns AB, EF and MN (mentioned below) applicable for 1 minute dataset.

```
Parameter  Lower limit  Upper limit
AB  50  3.5*C1
EF  30  2.0*C1*C2^1.2
MN  25  2.5*C2^2.0
```

I have averaged 1-minute dataset to compute 30-minutes, 6 hours, daily and monthly data and for time-averaged datasets, I have considered only D/T, AB, EF and MN columns. I have not considered C1 and C2 as they are like constants, so averaging them doesn't make sense as per my task.

A sample of 30-minutes averaged data is as follows:

```
D/T  AB  EF
20100101W00:00:00  120  30
20100101W00:30:00  125  29
20100101W01:00:00  122  38
20100101W01:30:00  121  31  
..
..
```

I need to identify outliers in 30-minutes average using lower and upper limits but the lower and upper limits are applicable to 1 minute data. My question is that can these limits be applicable on 30-minutes calculated averaged data also?

Secondly, 30-minutes data does not contain C1 and C2 columns but the calculation of limits contain C1 and C2, then how can I apply these limits on 30-minutes data?

My objective is to find out that how many records of 30-minutes average data are outside these limits.